# Why Copy Editor badge progress bar doesn't count tag wiki edits?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edit-badges, badge-progress

On the Review page, if I check my progress towards Copy Editor badge, it shows 3/500.
However, I've already been awarded Research Assistant, as well as Strunk & White for editing tag wikis [this is on [B&CG]](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com).

Why aren't tag wiki edits counted in the Copy Editor badge progress bar?

Comment: Ah. This might explain why I've got the badge on Programmers despite being about 20 edits short according to the progress bar.

Comment: I had reported this on [CogSci](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/477/edit-count-dropped-suddenly) as well.  I think the backend portion has been fixed, but they may still be working on the progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. *All* edits to tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts are now counted, regardless of whether or not you are considered the *owner* of the tag wiki/excerpt.

[See this answer on Cognitive Sciences Meta for a little more info](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/a/483/2370).

Comment: You're right - seems to be working fine now. Thanks for the answer.