# Community is flagging good posts with "Low answer quality score [-1]"

Tags: bug, status-completed, automatic-flags

On Linguistics, where I am currently one of the moderators, I just received automatic Low Quality flags on two posts. Both posts have quality score -1 (typical scores are 0 - 100). These posts are anything but low quality, particularly that low, so it seems that Community is having a problem calculating post quality scores.

Example posts that Community has flagged recently include:

- Linguistics: [1](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2829/does-english-language-stand-special-in-terms-of-phonology/2834#2834), [2](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/argot-vs-jargon/2833#2833)
- Unix & Linux: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55533/is-there-a-reason-why-owner-permissions-exist-arent-group-permissions-enough/55538#55538)
- Cross Validated: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43443/basic-question-about-gradient-descent/43444#43444), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43339/whats-wrong-with-xkcds-frequentists-vs-bayesians-comic/43442#43442), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43436/whats-the-advantages-of-bayesian-version-of-linear-regression-logistic-regress/43441#43441)
- Server Fault: [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/425252/how-can-i-disable-dnssc-for-google-apps-gmail-mx-records-on-my-authoritative-d/447995#447995)
- Programmers: [1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175589/should-i-expect-my-team-to-have-more-than-a-basic-proficiency-with-our-source-co/175620#175620), [2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175584/demonstrate-bad-code-to-client/175621#175621)
- Meta Programmers: [1](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/25936)
- GIS: [1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40937/how-to-convert-polygon-layer-to-txt-files/40939#40939)
- Physics: [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44037/why-is-near-field-communication-nfc-range-limited-to-about-20cm/44089#44089)! [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33767/classical-limit-of-schrodinger-equation/44091#44091) [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44087/if-superposition-is-possible-in-qm-why-do-we-often-assume-systems-are-already-i/44092#44092) [4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44087/if-superposition-is-possible-in-qm-why-do-we-often-assume-systems-are-already-i/44093#44093)
- Mi Yodeya: [1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22236/472)
- Meta Stack Overflow: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155470/search-api-and-vs-or/155474#155474) [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155385/why-copy-editor-badge-progress-bar-doesnt-count-tag-wiki-edits/155475#155475) [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155365/missing-html-escape/155478#155478)
- Web Apps [1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35378/web-worker-postmessage-overhead/35382#35382), [2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35350/google-multiple-sign-in-fails-to-switch-users/35381#35381)
- Academia [1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/5248/53), [2](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/5249/53) (both from the same user)
- TeX/LaTeX: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82465/4012), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82468/4012), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82472/4012) [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82480/4427)

There have been reports from other sites as well (@ moderators from those sites: feel free to add your name here for reference).

Comment: We have received four such (invalid) flags on stats and one on GIS. I have left three of the flags on stats untouched in case anyone would like to investigate further: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43443/basic-question-about-gradient-descent/43444#43444, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43339/whats-wrong-with-xkcds-frequentists-vs-bayesians-comic/43442#43442, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43436/whats-the-advantages-of-bayesian-version-of-linear-regression-logistic-regress/43441#43441. NB: these flags are *not* vestiges of bad posts that have been edited.

Comment: One on SF too http://serverfault.com/questions/425252/how-can-i-disable-dnssc-for-google-apps-gmail-mx-records-on-my-authoritative-d/447995#447995

Comment: If you are referring to the low quality post queue, I think that some posts end up in there for *demonstration purposes*, so for example if someone flags that post as low quality the system will basically tell them that that they should pay more attention next time since it is not in fact low quality (more often you will see the reverse where a question that is poor quality and the reviewer says that its OK).

Comment: @Jack: These are automagic flags that mods get to see.

Comment: @Iain Thanks, added. :)

Comment: It's on Workplace too, pretty sure it's just all/most new answers coing in

Comment: Community is probably on a badge run for  Marshal...

Comment: @BenBrocka It's not all, I checked for that

Comment: Probably ninja edits...

Comment: Also on physics. [This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/44089/520) was flagged! Also the flags only show on the "moderator flags page", not on the affected posts.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ I'd believe that about one or two, but there seem to be *a lot*.

Comment: @Null It's not the result of edits: *every* new answer (but not question) coming in is getting flagged.  (I have been monitoring stats and GIS closely as a check.) Note, too, that a "-1" quality score is unprecedented: it takes a really awful answer to drop below 70 or so.

Comment: [According to the SF blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/2012/03/06/architecting-for-uptime/) new commits are pushed to meta and the rest of SE before SO, which implies, as this is not showing up on SO that it _is_ a new commit.

Comment: @Jack was referring to [Review-beta: Obviously good answer in low-quality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142998/review-beta-obviously-good-answer-in-low-quality)

Comment: We just got flooded on Math.SE with 36 Community flagged "low quality" flags in the last hour.

Comment: Hehe! My latest answers just got flagged. I admit it's nothing special...

Comment: The flags also can't be counterflagged; I got the message "There are no remaining flags on this post"

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen That is exactly what I was referring to, but it seems like this is a different issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's my fault - `!` is a tricky operator.

We'll be pushing a fix out now and cleaning up the flag queues.

My apologies to all moderators.

Comment: Could this be related to - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155482/i-flagged-a-post-as-very-low-quality-and-it-was-not-the-last-close-vote-but-i?

Comment: `! is a tricky operator.` No; it's not.

Comment: Note that this post has been automatically flagged as low-quality.

Comment: @DavidFullerton I have no idea what you're talking about :P

Comment: You mean `if (!!!!!x++)` is tricky??? ;)

Comment: Anyone who says `!` isn't a tricky operator has never tried to coerce an arbitrary variable in javascript into a boolean (not that I'd recommend trying that).