# Moderator overlay missing for LQ posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

Since [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155471/community-is-flagging-good-posts-with-low-answer-quality-score-1) happened the overlay at the bottom of the screen that contains the moderator action buttons has been missing from posts automagically flagged as Low Quality.

It looks like posts flagged for other reasons still get the overlay as expected.

May we have it back for LQ posts please?

Comment: Looks like the other issue is fixed, but I'm still seeing a missing overlay. Last answer to do this to me was [this diy question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/13563/why-do-my-new-dimmable-cfl-bulbs-hum/20709#20709)

Comment: @BMitch: or *not* seeing the missing overlay :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed for future flags - and it was also my fault.  Refactoring is hard.

Comment: Let's go shopping.